# Bidirectional processes by FIFO pipeline

Tags: c

I am asked to do two chat programs so that user1 & user2 can send and receive the messages. The program should ask the user if he needs to continue chatting or no after every message is sent,
and If no, a goodbye message should be printed on the standard
output to inform the other user that chatting is terminated. Also, each user is allowed to send only up to 5 messages.

I created the next codes for the user1 and user2
the code of user 1:
"""

```
//Chat 1
// This side writes first, then reads
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, count=0,sendAgain=0;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";// Declare the FIFO file pathname
   
    // Creating the named file(FIFO) 
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); // mkfifo(<pathname>, <permission>)
   
    char Arr1[80], Arr2[80];
    
    while (1)
    {
        // ***Open FIFO for write only****
       fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); 
       while (count!=5){
        count++ ;  
        printf("\nYour message: ");
       fgets(Arr1, 80, stdin);// Take an input Arr1 from user with maximum 100 length
       write(fd, Arr1, strlen(Arr1)+1);// Write the input Arr1 on FIFO
       printf("Do you want to continue?[1 or 2]\n1-Yes\n2-No\nAnswer: ");
       scanf("%d",&sendAgain);
       getchar();
       if (sendAgain==2) {
           break;
           
       }
       
       }
       write(fd, "bye", strlen("bye")+1);
       close(fd);// close the FIFO
       
       
       // ***Open FIFO for read only****
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, Arr2, sizeof(Arr2));// Read from FIFO
        printf("User2: %s\n", Arr2);// Print the message that was read 
        close(fd);// close the FIFO
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"""
and the code of the user 2
"""

```
//Chat 2
// This side reads first, then writes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd1, count=0,YN=0;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";// Declare the FIFO file pathname
   
    // Creating the named file(FIFO) 
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); // mkfifo(<pathname>, <permission>)
   
    char str1[80], str2[80];
    
    while (1)
    {
        // ***Open FIFO for read only****
        fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
        read(fd1, str1, 80);
        printf("User1: %s\n", str1);// Print the message that was read
        close(fd1);
        
         // ***Open FIFO for read only****
       fd1 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); 
       while (count!=5){
        count++ ;  
        printf("\nYour message: ");
       fgets(str2, 80, stdin);// Take an input WriteArr from user with maximum 100 length
       write(fd1, str2, strlen(str2)+1);// Write the input WriteArr on FIFO
       printf("Do you want to continue?[enter 1 or 2]\n1-Yes\n2-No\nAnswer: ");
       scanf("%d",&sendAgain);
       getchar();
       if (sendAgain==2) {
           break;
           
       }
       
       }
       write(fd1, "bye", strlen("bye")+1);
       close(fd1);// close the FIFO
      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"""
However, I faced a problem after I wrote a message and was asked if I wanted to continue, it allows me to write a message again if I said yes but without reading it from the other user and the program is stopping at this point. Also, if I chose "No" it ends the program without printing "bye" or even waiting for the other's user turn to write!
[Output1 if yes entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNTB.png)

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIV2C.png)

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and trace the flow so that you can find out exactly what it is doing and why. Finding out why it is exiting unexpectedly should be a simple matter of stepping thru the code line by line. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @kaylum I'm not sure the OP will find "Do basic debugging" to be terribly helpful. Personally, I'm not sure that link will prove helpful in this case, either, especially as it doesn't feature the use of a debugger, though that is more my opinion

Comment: @Mera without having run your code, is there a reason that you use all of `fgets`, `scanf`, and `getchar`? In my experience, bad things tend to happen in C when mixing i/o methods without extra caution.

Comment: @MANA624 It's not terribly helpful if you just want someone to solve the problem for you. It is helpful if you want to learn to solve problems for yourself rather than turn to others for help all the time. Encouraging others to develop and at least attempt effective debugging first is more valuable in the long term than just solving this one problem. My opinion.

Comment: Most of the functions you use have return values you should check.

Comment: What is `sendagain` in the client code?